# How to change whole font to arial in overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, fontfamily

I want to know which command i have to use to set the whole document font from times to arial in **overleaf**? i have seen some threads suggesting to use helvet which is close to arial.

It would be a huge help if you could suggest me the code for arial font and where to put it.

Regards,
SZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working in overleaf, then use `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX` compiler and add these commands in *preamble* after `\documentclass{}`:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
```

Comment: do i install XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX ? i mean how does it work?

Comment: No, Use this link to find how to change compiler. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Changing_compiler

Comment: thanks ... didn't know that the compiler can be changed .... the arial font works there..